# Handle all registry keys without restart in C#

Tags: c#, registry

i have make keys to **Disable Task Manager**

on changing its value it works

but some of the keys required to **log off or restart Window**(e.g. Change Desktop background)

**is it possible take effect of all registry keys without restarting Window?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use .NET framework classes to access Registry.

Check 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/modifyregistry.aspx

It will help you I think.